# Geoserver : How to set a remote OSM WMS/WMTS connection

Tags: openstreetmap, geoserver, wms

I want to set some WMS/WMTS in order to add several basemap (for instance : OSM or other). I tried to set a new WMTS connection :

[https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](https://tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png)

But i have an error message : connection time out.

Could you tell me how to do? I paste a screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer can only cascade WMS and WMTS services, these standards require a `getCapabilities` end point, which is what is entered in the Datastore page.

OSM is an XYZ or TMS service and is not (currently) supported by GeoServer for cascading. It would be possible to add the ability but currently no one has bothered.

It may be possible to use GeoWebCache to directly fetch OSM tiles and cache them for you, but I've never tried this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it helps you but there are some services that provide OSM WMS service, some of them are free (at least for non-commercial use), [check it here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WMS). I tried to add [this one](https://www.osm-wms.de/) to GeoServer and it worked for me, using the capabilities URL described if you press **Info & Contact** on [this site](https://www.osm-wms.de/).